# Should I use R or Octave for modification of tab delimitated text files?

Tags: r, octave

I have a bunch of text files with tab delimited data, like so

```
X    Y    Z
1    2    Q
K    4    2
```

I want to examine these for certain properties, and then modify them in different ways depending on the result, eventually creating new text files with information added and/or deleted.

Now, according to my own investigations, both R and Octave could probably do this. Should I prefer one of them over the other for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without saying what you want to do for analysis it's impossible to tell.  If you need to do a logistic regression on each one in order to add the residuals then R is your best bet.  Octave might be better for other things (maybe most simple things).

Comment: If I would tell you that I have no idea what an "logistic regression" is, would that help to determine the level of complexity of the things I want to do? :) Basically it is things like "If [x,y] is a, add q to [x,z]. Else, add r to [x,z]". It should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: won't matter much which you pick... pick which one you know better.  If you don't know either then pick which one fits your future knowledge needs better.  Ask someone more senior in you field which that is.

Comment: I don't know. Just for the first task, importing the data, this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198428/load-a-text-file-containing-both-numbers-and-letters) is what I need to do in Octave while I can just write `X <- read.table("X.txt")` in R. It didn't start out well for Octave here.

Comment: In addition, whether Octave or R is most appropriate also depends on what the people around you use. If most of your colleagues use Matlab/Octave, it might be a good choice to go for Octave. Same holds for R.