# Load a text file containing both numbers and letters

Tags: octave

I have a text file that looks like so:

```
A    B    C
1    2    3
```

(This is just a minimal example of what I actually have. My actual files are HUGE and vary in number of rows.)

I would like to load in this file into Octave. However, the file contains letters, rather than just numbers. When I'm trying to apply the load function, I get errors, and I guess this is because the load function only accepts numbers. *What function should I use instead?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call fopen, fscanf, and fclose. The format string must be different for lines containing only letters (like `'%s\t%s\t%s'`), and for those which contain only numbers (like `'%g\t%g\t%g'`). You can read lines of identical structure with a single fprintf call.

Example file (data.txt):

```
A        B        C
D        E        F
1        2        3
4        5        6
7        8        9
10       11       12
```

Suppose that we know in advance that the file contains 3 columns, and 2 lines with characters at the beginning:

```
fid = fopen('data.txt', 'r');
[x, nx] = fscanf(fid, '%s\t%s\t%s', [3, 2]);
[y, ny] = fscanf(fid, '%g\t%g\t%g', [3, Inf]);
fclose(fid);
```

The lines with the characters will be in `x'`, and the lines with numbers will be contained by `y'`.

Comment: Well, this was really just a minimal example for what I actually have (which are a number of massive text files where the number of rows vary).

Comment: Is there any structure, I mean, can you tell in advance which rows will contain only letters, and which rows will only contain numbers?

Comment: Yes. I know that the first row and the second column will contains only letters. Everything else is numbers.

Comment: @Speldosa I added example code to my answer. I tried it (in Matlab, I don't have Octave installed), and it works. Note that the size argument of fprintf is tricky, and the matrices read must be transposed!

Comment: Thanks! I'll mark this as accepted in a bit. I'm just curious to know if there isn't some more convenient, general way where you don't really have to know so much about your data. For example, in R, you just type `X <- read.table("X.txt")` and that's basically it.