# Load a text file containing both numbers and letters 2

Tags: text-files, octave

This question is related to [Load a text file containing both numbers and letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198428/load-a-text-file-containing-both-numbers-and-letters) but I ask for the opposite

```
blabla<tab>1
blabla<tab>2
...
```

Do I need fscanf in this case also?

EDIT: the answer to the question mentioned seams to be for treating individual characters as cols. In my case, I have strings of different length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the textread function. It solved the problem.